# Facebook All-day events show up in Google Calendar a day early

Tags: facebook, google-calendar, facebook-events, apple-ical

I have, using the export feature in Facebook, imported the ical feed in Google Calendar for Events. This works as it should, except that events that have no hour defined, show up a day early in Google Calendar (as full-day events). Events that have an hour defined show up at the correct time though. Anybody have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I just performed the same export of Facebook events that you described above and did not encounter this problem.  The events show up on the proper day and time.  I believe the difference was that you manually exported the iCal from Facebook and imported into Google Calendar.  However, when I opened it in Facebook, Google Calendar automatically handled the link and asked me if I wanted to import it.

Use Chrome and go here: `chrome://chrome/settings/handlers`

This will show you if you have any handlers for webcals.  If not, when going to Google Calendar it should prompt you whether you want to use this to handle webcal links and accept.

Comment: I just let it open using Outlook on my work pc, and there it had the same problem. Might it have something to do with my timezone?

Comment: If it was a timezone issue seems like it should be offset by a certain number of hours instead of being an all day event.

Comment: but it is exactly the all day events that get moved a day. Events that have a specific time are correct. Which would also make it strange that it would be a timezone issue, though.